# In a Blazor WASM get raw oauth tokens?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have an authenticated user in a Blazor WebAssembly application via the OidcAuthentication provider. I know how to checkout all of the claims from the user object via the `AuthenticationStateProvider` but is there anyway to get the raw oauth token in my Blazor pages?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `IAccessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken`

[See more here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/blazor-wasm/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/Services)

[See also this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#retrieve-and-attach-the-access-token-to-the-response) / [and this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/blazor-wasm/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/Services/RemoteAuthenticationService.cs)

hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks. That was the missing piece. Not sure why I didn't find that sooner.